# `bash: scp: command not found` while I do have `scp` in `$PATH`

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

Sorry for cross posting of this question which is also posted at [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1208028)

About `off-topic`: The remote server is **ubuntu**, the client side is on linux mint.

Here is my screen copy:

[image]

As shown in the screen copy, the `scp` command failed with

```
bash: scp: command not found
lost connection
```

However after I ssh into the remote server and type `scp` I can see that command is available, and my `$PATH` environment is good.

If I tried to install `openssh-client` as suggested in many places it says the `openssh-client is already the newest version`

Now I am stucked and don't know what's wrong with the `scp` command. Any idea?

**Update**

I have `openssh-client` installed locally, nothing wrong with the local environment:

[image]

**Updates II**

A screen copy shows that `scp` command available on both ends:

[image]

Comment: Since you are trying to `scp` **from** your local machine (`luog-Sattelite-P50A`) **that's** the one that needs to have `openssh-client` installed on it - the fact that it's installed and in your `PATH` on the remote server is irrelevant.

Comment: Being an native linux user for 5 years and play with computer for over 20 years I know exactly what I am talking about. No, my local mint 18 has the scp installed from the very beginning. And yes I can scp to many other remote servers.

Comment: The comment about the remote server having `scp` being irrelevant is based on your question's text and image. At no point do you say, or show, that `scp` is in the `PATH` of `luog@loug-Satellite-P50-A`, or that `openssh-client` is installed there, let alone current. Based on your question we can only presume that you haven't checked those facts. I've been using computers for 4½ _decades_ and yet I still have __Doh!__ moments. They happen. Please update the question to show output from investigations on the _local_ system.

Comment: Please see updates to the question

Comment: a) Don't cross-post. b) Please don't post screenshots of text.

Comment: Use text for textual output.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to use `scp`, you need the `scp` binary in both client and server (and therefore installed `openssh-client` package)!

Comment: Ha! Didn't realize that for a looong time.